# Not able to include AndroidHttpTransport in my project

Tags: android, web-services, jar, include

am new to android working on web services. And trying to include AndroidHttpTransport class to my project from which is showing me some error.  When am searching on internet i got some [link](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/list)  and even some procedure to download jar and  [that is](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse?tm=2) 
But am unable to trace. Can any one tell me the clear procedure to include the AndroidHttpTransport class into the project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: finally got the link for downloading correct jar file to include AndroidHttpTransport and that is    http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar&can=2&q=     this is the direct link to download the jar

Answer (score 8):

It is deprecated, replace with `HttpTransportSE`.